# Concatenated numbers stuck in scientific notation MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to concatenate two columns of numbers, Column A and Column B. Both columns are stored as numbers in the underlying table. Column A varies from 1-9 numbers, and Column B is 2 or 3 numbers. The combination of 9 numbers in column B and 3 numbers in column B forces column A to be displayed in scientific notation before merging with Column B, resulting in an error.

So far I have tried the following expressions:

```
[Table].[ColumnA]&[Table].[ColumnB]

Val([Table].[ColumnA]&[Table].[ColumnB])

FormatNumber([Table].[ColumnA]&[Table].[ColumnB],0)
```

It seems like "&" is forcing columns A and B into text to be joined, but any formatting functions are converting after. How do I make sure both columns stay numbers before, during and after merging?

Answer (score 0):

Set field in table as LongInteger or Double type and then all 9 digits should display. Do not use Single or Integer.

Or use CDbl([ColumnA]) in query.

Regardless, the result of concatenation is a string, not a number value.

Comment: Generally speaking, is there a concatenation standard for numbers? I am frequently needing to concatenate two numbers and have them behave as numbers by exporting to excel and using =CONCAT(), then =VALUE() and importing back.

Comment: Even though the result is a string, if it contains only digits, it can often be dealt with like a number. Otherwise, use a conversion function to cast the value into a number type.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the last combination:

```
Format([Table].[ColumnA],"0") & Format([Table].[ColumnB],"0")
```